# The ScrollView component doesn't scroll to the selected item

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform

When clicked on the category the ScrollView component doesn't automatically scroll to the selected category adjusting the category to the given width on the screen. When I scroll manually and choose the category that is off the screen (i.e. rightmost) it then scrolls back to the start even though I have a chosen category which is now again off the screen.

Put in more simple words: I see a categories bar, I scroll to the right to choose 'Ice-cream', I choose it, the scrollBar immediately scrolls back the start although I can see ice-creams rendered below.

Why is that?

the code snippet:

```js
const categories = ['PIZZA', 'BURGERS', 'SUSHI', 'SODA', 'ICE-CREAM'];
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(categories[0]);


const CategoryList = () => {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const index = categories.indexOf(selectedCategory);
    scrollToCategory(index);
  }, [selectedCategory]);

  const handleCategoryPress = (index) => {
    setSelectedCategory(categories[index]);
  };

  const scrollToCategory = (index) => {
    if (scrollViewRef.current) {
      const categoryWidth = 60; // Adjust this value based on the category item width
      const offset = index * categoryWidth;
      scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ x: offset, animated: true });
    }
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView
      ref={scrollViewRef}
      horizontal
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    >
      <View className="flex-row space-x-5 mb-5 ml-5 mr-5">
        {categories.map((category, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            activeOpacity={0.8}
            onPress={() => handleCategoryPress(index)}
          >
            <Text
              style={[
                styles.categoryText, 
                selectedCategory === category && styles.categoryTextSelected
              ]}
            >
              {category}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Comment: Did you try using a Flatlist?

Comment: @MichaelBahl yes i did, still didn't work